# Getting the ticks in d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

How can I generate an array of ticks in d3 v4? So for example I have my x scale setup, and the range is `0 - 1000`, I want 4 ticks so it'd be `[0, 250, 500, 1000]` or the range is `2017-June - 2018-June` to 10 ticks then the result would be something like `[2017-June, 2017-Aug, ..., ...,]` etc.

I've tried this but it returns a function

```
d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need, for example, 4 ticks for range 0-1000 without svg creation, you may generate them like this:

```js
var rangeStart = 0;
var rangeEnd = 1000;

var numberOfTicks = 4;
var step = (rangeEnd - rangeStart) / numberOfTicks;

var result = d3.range(rangeStart, rangeEnd, step)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That won't get an array though

Comment: "I've tried this but it returns a function `d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10);`". Yes, it's should return function and this function you pass to method `call` that you call on svg node (see code of example). I updated answer.

Comment: Can you show all the existing code of your chart? May be i incorrectly understood your question.

Comment: I want an array of ticks eg. [1,2,3] I'm not using it for the SVG

Comment: Oh, you don't need svg creation, only array. I understood and updated answer.

Comment: Good answer, +1, but I edited it: no need to send OP to another site if you can do this using the Stack snippet.